# Implementation of SslErrorHandler proceed() function

Tags: android, security, ssl, webview

I am trying to learn what happens at the code level in Android when SslErrorHandler.proceed() (from class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/SslErrorHandler.html) is called in WebviewClient's onReceivedSslError function.

The documentation in the link above further mentions:

> Instances of this class are created by the WebView and passed to
>   onReceivedSslError(WebView, SslErrorHandler, SslError)

However, on looking up code in Webview.java, I don't see any SslErrorHandler object being created. Any pointers for me to understand this further?

Comment: Link to source code ? Or are you looking at decompiled code ?

Comment: Link to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to locate the implementation @ https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/glue/java/src/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java?rcl=439465f8724d4b502355d3683aa8dad2ff076ebf&l=950